# Getting spurious or garbled ISRs upon startup of x86 OS

Tags: c, assembly, interrupt, osdev

I have been working on an x86 OS using GRUB-multiboot as of late and have run into a problem concerning the IDT (*or more specifically ISRs*). Upon starting up my OS, an ISR is generated and then no more are, no matter how many times I press the keyboard or anything.

[image: Image of my OS upon startup]

I am using assembly stubs to be able to call `iret` at the end of the interrupts (*I have to do it this way do to the way I pass registers to the interrupt handlers so I cannot simply use `__attribute__((interrupt))`*)

```
.extern irq_handler_next
.extern isr_handler_next
.globl isr_handler
.globl irq_handler

irq_handler:
    pusha                 # Push all general purpose registers
    cld                    # Clear direction flag (forward movement)
    call irq_handler_next
    popa                  # Restore all general purpose registers
    iret                  # IRET will restore required parts of EFLAGS
                           #   including the direction flag
isr_handler:
    call isr_handler_next
    iret                  # IRET will restore required parts of EFLAGS
                           #   including the direction flag
```

And lastly my `C` code in which I initialize my IDT and have the `irq_handler_next` and `isr_handler_next` functions.
`idt.c`:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include "idt.h"
#include "lib/stdio.h"
#include "include/io.h"

// Define the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT)
struct idt_entry_t idt[IDT_ENTRIES];
struct idt_entry_t idt_entries[IDT_ENTRIES];

// Load the IDT pointer
struct idt_ptr_t idt_ptr = {
    .limit = sizeof(idt) - 1,
    .base = (uint32_t)&idt
};

typedef struct registers {
    uint32_t ds;                                     // Data segment selector
    uint32_t edi, esi, ebp, esp, ebx, edx, ecx, eax;  // Pushed by pusha
    uint32_t int_no, err_code;                       // Interrupt number and error code (if applicable)
    uint32_t eip, cs, eflags, useresp, ss;           // Pushed by the processor automatically
} registers_t;

// Define an IRQ handler function
void irq_handler_next(registers_t *regs)
{
    uint8_t irq = regs->int_no;
    if (irq >= PIC1_IRQ_BASE && irq < PIC1_IRQ_BASE + 8) {
        irq -= PIC1_IRQ_BASE;
    } else if (irq >= PIC2_IRQ_BASE && irq < PIC2_IRQ_BASE + 8) {
        irq -= PIC2_IRQ_BASE;
    }
    nanos_printf("Received IRQ %d!\n", irq);

    // Send an EOI (end-of-interrupt) signal to the PICs
    if (irq >= 8 && irq <= 15) {
        outb(PIC2_COMMAND, 0x20);
    }
    outb(PIC1_COMMAND, 0x20);

    __asm__ __volatile__("sti");
    return;
}


void isr_handler_next(int isr_num)
{
    nanos_printf("\nISR Number: %d\n", isr_num);

}


void idt_load()
{
    asm volatile("lidt %0" : : "m"(idt_ptr));
}

void idt_init(void)
{   
    // Disable interrupts
    __asm__ __volatile__("cli");

    // Setup the PIC(s)
    outb(0x20, 0x11);
    outb(0xA0, 0x11);
    outb(0x21, 0x20);
    outb(0xA1, 0x28);
    outb(0x21, 0x04);
    outb(0x21, 0x01);
    outb(0x21, 0xFB);
    outb(0xA1, 0xFF);

    // Print a message to indicate that IDT is being loaded
    nanos_printf("Loading IDT\n");

    // Initialize the IDT pointer
    idt_ptr.limit = sizeof(idt) - 1;
    idt_ptr.base = (uint32_t)&idt;

    // Set each IDT entry to the default handler
    for (int i = 0; i < IDT_ENTRIES; i++)
    {
        if (i != 7)
        {
             idt_set_gate(i, (uint32_t)isr_handler, 0x08, 0x8E);
        }
    }

    idt_set_gate(33, (uint32_t)irq_handler, 0x08, 0x8E);

    // Send initialization control word 1 and 2 to both PICs
    outb(PIC1_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4); // Initialization Control Word 1
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_COMMAND, ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4);
    io_wait();

    // Send initialization control word 3 to both PICs
    outb(PIC1_DATA, 0x20); // Initialization Control Word 3: IRQ 0-7 map to IDT entries 0x20-0x27
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, 0x28); // Initialization Control Word 3: IRQ 8-15 map to IDT entries 0x28-0x2F
    io_wait();
    

    // From @Michael_Petch on StackOverflow :D
    outb(PIC1_DATA, 4); io_wait(); outb(PIC2_DATA, 2); io_wait();

    
    // Send initialization control word 4 to both PICs
    outb(PIC1_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();
    outb(PIC2_DATA, ICW4_8086);
    io_wait();

       // Enable keyboard interrupts
    outb(0x21, inb(0x21) & ~(1 << 1));

    // Disable the PIT
    outb(0x43, 0x30); // send the control word to channel 0
    outb(0x40, 0x00); // send the initial count value (LSB)
    outb(0x40, 0x00); // send the initial count value (MSB)
    outb(0x21, 0xFC); // mask IRQ 0 and IRQ 1 (disable the PIT)


    // Load IDT
    idt_load();

    // Enable interrupts
    __asm__ __volatile__("sti");

    nanos_printf("IDT loaded\n");
}




void idt_set_gate(uint8_t num, uint32_t base, uint16_t sel, uint8_t flags)
{
    // Set the base address
    idt[num].base_lo = base & 0xFFFF;
    idt[num].base_hi = (base >> 16) & 0xFFFF;

    // Set the selector
    idt[num].sel = sel;

    // Set the always0 field
    idt[num].always0 = 0;

    // Set the flags
    idt[num].flags = flags;
}
```

So, my code is meant to initialize the IDT and allow for interrupts to happen, I was expecting to press the keyboard and have various `IRQ 0x01` messages come up, yet I only get that one mangled interrupt immediately upon startup.

Comment: So `isr_num` has a garbage value inside `isr_handler_next`. Hmm, where is that value coming from? I see a `call isr_handler_next` but it's not clear to me where the argument is being passed.

Comment: @teapot418 the `isr_num` is automatically passed by the PIC when an ISR takes place, this happens in hardware.

Comment: I'm very confused.  The `irq_handler_next` function expects one pointer argument on the stack, so it would be the responsibility of the caller `irq_handler` to set up and push it.  But it doesn't.  The top of the stack on entry to `irq_handler_next`, above the return address, will be the `edi` value that was pushed by `pusha`.  Which comes from whatever code was interrupted, and has no meaning as far as your handler is concerned.

Comment: Your `registers_t` isn't going to allocate and populate itself, you have to write the code to do that.  The PIC isn't doing it either - it has no access to CPU registers and memory, you talk to it via the i/o ports.  It seems like you're expecting some kind of magic to occur, but I'm not sure what you expect or why.

Comment: And as @teapot418 says, there's the same issue with the `isr_num` argument to `isr_handler_next`.  I do not know of any part of the hardware that provides this to you; there is no possible place it could come from.

Comment: The real issue here is that you are using irq handlers that are not compatible with code from the James Molloy tutorial. Jame Molloy uses the structure `registers_t`. The IRQ number is not pushed on the stack automatically by the CPU. In the James Molloy tutorial it is pushed there by special stubs created by macros (macro `IRQ`) that include pushing of an interrupt number.

Comment: @user21223562.   The pic does no such thing.  The pic causes the processor to grab one of 256 idt entries to gate through.   The typical approach to uncovering your vector is to have the gates point at a bunch of routines like: `trap0: push $0; jmp icommon; trap1: push $1; jmp icommon; trap2: push $2; jmp icommon; ... trap255: push $255; jump icommon` and point idt[i] at trap#i.  For 40years this nonsense has been the industry standard.